# recycling view create issues in checkbox state of childview in ExpandablelListview android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

In my `ExpandableListview`, I am using `Imageview` and `Checkbox` for `childview` that resembles the shape image and name.

When I tick the `checkbox` of particular child item , the other child item also gets ticked, after scrolling the checked state changes.

I needed multiple values to be selected.

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private static final int[] EMPTY_STATE_SET = {};
    private static final int[] GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET =
            {android.R.attr.state_expanded};
    private static final int[][] GROUP_STATE_SETS = {
        EMPTY_STATE_SET, // 0
        GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET // 1
    };
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    private boolean[] itemCheckedBoolean =  new boolean[100]; 



    Bitmap bmp;
    LayoutInflater infalInflater;


    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();      
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(_context);   

        for (int i = 0; i < SearchWhiteDiamondsActivity.shape_list.size(); i++) {
            itemChecked.add(i, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {

        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

     @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);  
    Log.e("_childText", "karjeevch "+childText);


    int itemType = getChildType(groupPosition,childPosition);      


    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    switch (itemType) {

    case 0:
        viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView==null) {

            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();                
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_shape, null);
            viewHolder.shape_name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_chk_box);
            //viewHolder.shape_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_chk_box);
            viewHolder.img_shape_icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_shape);                


            imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://rosycontact.com/shashvat/images/"+childText.toLowerCase()+".png", viewHolder.img_shape_icon);                
            Log.e("shape", "karjeevshp "+childText);
            viewHolder.shape_name.setText(childText);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);               


           //final TextView shape_name_temp=viewHolder.shape_name;

           viewHolder.shape_name.setChecked(itemChecked.get(childPosition));
           final CheckBox shape_name_temp=viewHolder.shape_name;


           viewHolder.shape_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(position_of_click.contains (childPosition)){ 
                    position_of_click.remove(childPosition);
                } 
                else{ 
                    position_of_click.add(childPosition);
                }
            }
        });



           if(position_of_click.contains(childPosition)){ 
               viewHolder.shape_name.setChecked(true);
            }
           else{ 
               viewHolder.shape_name.setChecked(false);
        }

        }
        else{

            viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://rosycontact.com/shashvat/images/"+childText.toLowerCase()+".png", viewHolder.img_shape_icon);                                             
            viewHolder.shape_name.setText(childText);                               
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);                             
        }
        return convertView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common problem. Basically this appears due to memory reuse in adding child in the list.
You can overcome from this issue just maintain a list in which you stores the position of checked items, in your getView methods check that particular position is stored in list or not, if this position is stored in the list make them checked otherwise unchecked them.
To enter data in that list - when you checked on any check box add his position to list and and if position already exists remove from list.

Comment: I am a newbie .. Can u please provide some some examples ... will be great help for me , because I am stucked in this for 2 days

Comment: Simply just create a list ArrayList<String>position_of_click=new ArrayList<String>    in your onclick of checkbox check  if(position_of_click.contains (position)){ position_of_click.remove(position)} else{ position_of_click.add(position)}       and In your get view method    if(position_of_click.contains(position){  checkbox.setChecked(true)}else{  checkbox.setchecked (false)}

Comment: ok .. let me try this .. will post the reply ... pls have a look to my reply after 10 minutes ..

Comment: Didn't work bro ... I updated my getChildView code ..pls have a look

Comment: please make convertView=null before   if (convertView==null)

Comment: because it is recycle the old view

Comment: if I do this it works , but my childview in group 2 (case 1: )gets disturbed

Comment: case 0:
         viewHolder = null;
         convertView=null;
   if (convertView==null) {

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Override these two methods in your adapter class:

```
@Override
public int getGroupType(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getGroupType(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getGroupTypeCount();
}
```

or try this: override these:

```
@Override
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getChildType(groupPosition, childPosition);
}

@Override
public int getChildTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getChildTypeCount();
}
```

Comment: I got same issue in listview when extends **base adapter**, and solved this by override two methods: **getViewTypeCount()** and **getItemViewType()**, so i guess above will work in case extends **BaseExpandableListAdapter**

Comment: what should I do inside getItemViewType() & getViewTypeCount() methods

Comment: in my case i retern these: Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return position;
 }

 Override
 public int getViewTypeCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return getCount();
 }

Comment: Try to guess what should you return, TypeCount method should return total no. of items in list that time e.i. getCount() method

Comment: My class extends BaseExpandableListAdapter , still not able get these 2 methods

Comment: Yes bro i know, thats why i suggest you about above methods,, not these. ok bro see this: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004498/android-expandable-list-view)